# the error redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage. in next.js

Tags: next.js, redux, react-redux

I'm receiving this problem in my Next.js WebApp. I'm trying to establish local storage with persist-redux; if anyone can assist, here's my code:
`
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

import userReducer from "./user/userSlicer";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
key: "root",
version: 1,
storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
reducer: persistedReducer,
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
return getDefaultMiddleware({
serializableCheck: false,
});
},
});

export type RootState = ReturnType;

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;`

I was expecting having data saved in client browser storage

Comment: Did you remember to use the `"use client"` directive so this code runs client-side? If so, then we may need better details and a complete [mcve].